# Compiling and Running C++ file in Java Application

Tags: java, c++

I am trying to build a Java application that compiles and runs `C++` files. It also stores the output of the `.exe` file in a text file. Can anyone provide a complete walk through on how to do it?

I have already tried the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826814/compiling-and-running-c-program-in-java) and the program showed `compilation successful` message. But I couldn't find the .o file or `.exe` file in the directory.

Comment: Show your code, not someone else's.

Comment: "Can anyone provide a complete walk through on how to do it ?" Such a question is **WAY** too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

General question -> General Answer

Easiest way to do it: Generate a makefile, run that.

For make see [reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)

Comment: I'm sorry, but with that level of simplicity, he will introduce far too few dependencies and the job will execute too fast.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be a Java or a C++ problem. Are you certain your compiler is properly set up? What command are you using to invoke it?
Assuming you are using the code provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826814/compiling-and-running-c-program-in-java), are the paths indicated correct?

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C gcc " + filename + " -o " + exeName, null, dir);
```

Try opening a command prompt and invoking the compiler by hand:

```
gcc Hello.cpp
```

Assuming the paths are correct for both the executable and the file, you either get an error, or a file named something like $a.exe in your working directory.

Lastly: I haven't used Mingw32 in a while, but you might need to call g++ instead of gcc for C++ code.